# Update Google Compute Engine Instance type in real time

Tags: google-compute-engine

I would like to know if you can change the type of one instance to another, e.g:

n1-standard-1 to n1-standard-2

I don't see nothing to that in the documentation, but may be I miss something.

In case that is not posible, how i deal with this, there is another way to do this change?

Comment: See @user33629's answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need create a new instance with the new type.

1. Disconnect your persistent disk from n1-standard-1.
2. Create new instance in the same zone with the type n1-standard-2 and choose boot from disk. (choose the persistent disk)
3. Run the new instance.

Note: I recommend have a snapshot from the disk before to try this procedure.

for realtime you can choose in "boot from disk" choose the snapshot instead of the persistent disk. and when you test that this instance its working, associate the ip address from VM1 to VM2.

Comment: I am interested on change on "realtime". Why from snapshot? Cannot use the same disk?

Comment: Because you can't connect read-write disk to two instances in the same time and i can't see in the docs https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks a way to make a hot swap.

Comment: This is now out of date. See @user33629's answer below.

Answer (score 16):

You can stop the machine, edit it then launch it again. 
I just did it now and it worked fine.

switched from micro to small without changing my data.

Regards.

Comment: This is the easiest and best way.

Comment: This is now the way to do it.  It must be a new feature from Google since the Carlos's answer.  I just tried it and it went flawlessly.  Just make sure after you stop, edit, and change your instance type, that you scroll down to the bottom and click 'Save' before you start your instance again.

Comment: user33629 answer is correct. We did exactly this and it works perfectly. Used: n1-standard-1. Needed to upgrade. Stoped instance. Changed type from n1-standard-1 into n1-standard-2 (under 'Edit'). Started instance again. Done. Time needed: around 5 minutes.