# How to upgrade or swap google compute engine instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to upgrade my instance that have a wordpress site. Using the click to deploy it has two disk, one boot and another disk

I try this method

[Update Google Compute Engine Instance type in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115066/update-google-compute-engine-instance-type-in-real-time)
but the site does not work after

It just show Index
[image: index]
anyone have any idea why? I can access the phpmyadmin with same password and database is all there.. just the site not working

I have also try the clone method.. but didn't work as well..

Comment: What is it supposed to show? Have you configured the metadata, start-up scripts and tags for the new instance as for the old one? Have you tried cloning the old instance instead? Cloning takes care of replicating all the instance configuration (tags, metadata...) and you would need only to change the boot disk.

Comment: It is suppose to show a wordpress site that i launch with click to deploy. I will try your clone method

Comment: the clone doesn't work as well :(

Comment: It could also be that the public IP address changed when the instance got recreated.

Comment: Yes i updated that in phpmyadmin wp options for the wordpress setting. Do u mean that?

Answer (score 1):

Update the disk info in /etc/fstab file. It might be showing the older disk.