# Downgrade Google VM instance.

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am using google virtual machinen1-highcpu-4 (4 vCPUs, 3.6 GB memory). 
I want to downgrade it to n1-highcpu-2 ( 2 vCPU, 1.8 GB Memory).

Is it possible to downgrade it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update Google Compute Engine Instance type in real time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115066/update-google-compute-engine-instance-type-in-real-time)

Answer (score 1):

It is not really possible to downgrade it. What I do make a snapshot of the current VM, and then create a new VM with the specs I need, along with the snapshot as it's source disk